# Intuition for ground state degeneracy of Majorana checkerboard model

Tags: condensed-matter, lattice-model, topological-order, ground-state

I'm now trying to learn about Fracton. In the [very early paper studying Majorana checkerboard model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02576), it is claimed that the ground state degeneracy ${D_0}$ on ${L \times L \times L}$ 3-torus is ${log_2D_0 = 3L-3}$. Although this is proven nicely with algebraic representation, I don't have a good intuition in understanding it from the lattice model. Is there a way to understand the ground state degeneracy at the level of the lattice model?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of a commuting-projector Hamiltonian AKA a stabilizer Hamiltonian. What that means is, every term commutes with each other and the ground state is the +1 eigenstate of each of the Hamiltonian terms. These terms $S_i$ are called stabilizers because they *stabilize* the ground state $S_i\vert GS\rangle = \vert GS\rangle$. We will call this the stabilizer condition.

There are two ways to calculate the ground state degeneracy of stabilizer Hamiltonians. I think formalizing this idea (though I am not too familiar) gives you the derivation from the algebraic representation (i.e. this is an equivalent derivation). But the physical idea is quite intuitive. I will explain it using the quantum information terminology, which I believe is quite common in the physics literature nowadays.

Also, it is helpful to work out these ideas on a simpler stabilizer code (for example the toric code) before applying it to fractons. The idea is exactly the same, just that the counting is harder for fracton models.

### Approach I

**Count the number of qubits minus the number of independent stabilizers**

**Number of qubits**: We need two Majoranas to encode a full fermion, which is equivalent to a qubit. Therefore, our physical system consists of $L^3/2$ qubits. We will assume $L$ is even -- this is necessary to define the Hamiltonian with periodic boundary conditions.

**Independence of stabilizers**: Note that all the stabilizers are not independent. That is, once you set most of the stabilizers to be $+1$ for your state, the state automatically satisfies the stabilizer condition for the rest of the stabilizers. Counting the number of independent stabilizers is the most nontrivial part of this approach to calculating GSD.

A simple abstract example: Imagine a stabilizer Hamiltonian $H = -\sum_{i=1}^3 S_i$, where $S_3 = S_1S_2$. If you state satisfies the stabilizer condition for $S_1$ and $S_2$, it automatically satisfies the stabilizer condition for $S_3$. So we say that although this Hamiltonian has three terms, it only has two independent stabilizers.

For our problem, the Hamiltonian consists of $L^3/2$ terms. You can see that multiplying all the stabilizers in one plane gives you
$$ \prod_{i\in plane} S_i = 1.$$
Let us call these our plane redundancies. This means that there are $3L$ plane redundancies in our stabilizer count. But wait, we are overcounting the number of redundancies (at the risk of confusing you: there are redundancies in our redundancies)! There is the relation
$$ \bigcup_{p\in \text{xy planes}} \{S_i: i \in p \} = \bigcup_{p\in \text{yz planes}} \{S_i: i \in p \} = \bigcup_{p\in \text{zx planes}} \{S_i: i \in p \}.$$
So, we effectively have two redundancies in our redundancies, totaling our number of redundancies to $3L-2$. Therefore, the number of independent stabilizers we have is $L^3/2 - 3L+2$.

**Each stabilizer reduces the Hilbert space dimension by a factor of two**: Each stabilizer has eigenvalues +1 and -1. You can convince yourself that the dimension of both eigenspaces are equal (Hint: $\gamma_i$ is unitary). Therefore, when we apply the stabilizer condition on a state, we are halving the allowed Hilbert space dimension. It is nicer to think in terms of qubits. Equivalently, we can say, the number of qubits encoded in the allowed Hilbert space reduces by one. The total number of qubits encoded in the Hilbert space that satisfies all the stabilizer condition is therefore,
$$\#\text{Qubits encoded in ground space} = \#\text{Qubits} - \#\text{Independent stabilizers} = \log_2 D_0, $$
where $D_0$ is the ground state degeneracy.

**Conclusion**: Putting it all together, we find
$$\log_2 D_0 = L^3/2 - (L^3/2 - 3L+2) = 3L-2$$
and that's how you get the ground state degeneracy from this approach (I believe there's a typo in your question, this matches the paper you linked).

### Approach II

**Count the number of logical operators**

In the interest of space and time, I will just summarize this approach. The rough idea is the following: You have a physical Hilbert space of $n$ qubits and $l$ independent stabilizers. In principle, you can write down $n-l$ more operators that commute with your stabilizers and -- if you added them to your list of stabilizers -- would further reduce your ground state degeneracy. You can convince yourself that these operators necessarily have to act nontrivially within the ground space of your original model, and therefore are called logical operators (since they perform logical gates on your stored quantum information). In usual topological quantum codes such as the toric code and fracton models, these operators are those that create anyons, wind them around your torus, and annihilate them.

It is easy to see that counting the number of independent $n-l$ logical operators is equivalent to subtracting the number of independent stabilizers ($l$) from the number of qubits ($n$). This way of calculating the GSD has been used on the X-cube model in section IIIB of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00747) by Ma, Lake, Chen and Hermele. I can elaborate if you have any specific questions!

---

As you can see, both these physical approaches require a careful counting and making sure we don't miss any or overcount. This is why it is useful to have the algebraic representation which you can just plug into a computer and have it count for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! Yes I'm familiar with toric code and I usually think about its ground state degeneracy from the homotopy perspective, and your answer definitely helps providing new insights! And in terms of the typo, I'm referring to equation (9) in their paper, but I see that you are probably referring to Table IV, this left me a bit more confused....

Comment: I did not notice eqn 9, thanks for pointing it out. I think they clarified it better in the published version, in the note under the table. They say that, to get $3L-3$, you need to use a different boundary condition. I’m glad the answer was helpful!